# ImportError: cannot import name 'SubgradientStructuredSVM'

Tags: python, python-3.x, crf

I am using jupyter notebook, and installed pystruct using pip install pystruct

```
from pystruct.learners import SubgradientStructuredSVM
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'SubgradientStructuredSVM'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try:

```
from pystruct.learners import SubgradientSSVM
```

Please refer to the documentation for more information given in the link https://pystruct.github.io/generated/pystruct.learners.SubgradientSSVM.html.